# Esconder imagens do Carrousel ao abrir no celular e mostrar outras - Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Estou usando o componente **Carrousel** do bootstrap 4.

Minha intenção é fazer com que quando seja aberto no PC e Tablet, seja mostrado o slide com imagens originais.

Quando for aberto no celular, seja aberto outra imagem mais leve.

> Carrousel: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/
>
> Grid: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

```
<div id="carouselInicio" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagens/carrosel-site.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagens/carrosel-app.jpg"  alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagens/carrosel-arquitetura.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="imagens/carrosel-projetos.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselInicio" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselInicio" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize media queries, tente assim:

```css
#carouselInicio
{
  @media screen and (max-width: 720px)
  {
    display: none;
  }
}

#img-mobile
{
  display: none;
  @media screen and (max-width: 720px)
  {
    display: block;
  }
}
```